# Simple polymorphic joins return Unknown Column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I seem to be missing something on a seemingly simple query involving a join and `has_many ..., class_name: ...`

(Sorry for the contrived example, but here we go:)

Let's imagine we have Caravans. Caravans can be towed, and a car can tow multiple caravans. Each caravan can have a single person in it, and each car towing the caravan can have a single person in it. There are different types of person, so the person field is polymorphic:

```
class Car < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :person, polymorphic: true
  has_many :caravans, class_name: 'CarTowedCaravan'
end

class CarTowedCaravan < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :car
  belongs_to :person, polymorphic: true
end
```

... and I want to find out if there is a Caravan containing Jack that is being towed by a Car containing Jill.

So I think I could do

```
Car.joins(:caravans).where(person: jill, caravan: { person: jack }).any?
```

Yet when I try to do this, I get:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'caravans.person_type' in 'where clause': 
SELECT 1 AS one FROM `cars` 
  INNER JOIN `car_towed_caravans` ON `car_towed_caravans`.`car_id` = `car`.`id` 
  WHERE `cars`.`person_type` = 'Intellectual' 
    AND `cars`.`person_id` = 1 
    AND `caravans`.`person_type` = 'Clown' 
    AND `caravans`.`person_id` = 1
    LIMIT 1
```

Yet I can do it with a bit of SQL:

```
Car.joins('INNER JOIN car_towed_caravans AS caravans ON caravans.car_id = car.id')
   .where(person: jill, caravan: { person: jack }).any?
```

That's pretty much exactly what rails is doing anyway, except adding `AS caravan` - and yet rails surely knows that I want to call it a caravan.

I'm trying to work out whether this is a bug, or maybe there's a hint I could give the join to make it add the `AS caravans` fragment, or maybe non-obviously there's no way ActiveRecord could reliably do something like this? `includes(:caravans)` seems to have the same problem.

But ultimately, is there a cleaner way of doing this? Or is rails telling me to stop being lazy and call them `car_towed_caravans` throughout?

Comment: One of the anomalies about the Rails implementation of the where statement is that the reference to the association actually needs to use the table name.  So I think the correct format is `Car.joins(:caravans).where(person: jill, car_towed_caravans: { person: jack }).any?`

Comment: @SteveTurczyn Afraid not - get `Unknown column 'car_towed_caravans.person'` - because it isn't associated with the association, so it stops treating it as polymorphic. Could do `Car.joins(:caravans).where(person: jill, car_towed_caravans: { person_id: jack.id, person_type: jack.class.name }).any?` which is maybe a bit better....

Comment: Yes, good catch!  Although when you have to jump through that many hoops the plan SQL keeps looking more and more attractive. :)